# What is a Number with Feeling™?

Tags: pattern, knowledge, number-sequence, computer-puzzle

*In the spirit of the What is a Word™/Phrase™ series started by JLee, a special brand of Phrase™ and Word™ puzzles.*

---

If a number conforms to a special rule, I call it a Number with Feeling™.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Numbers with Feeling™ | Not numbers with Feeling™ |
| --- | --- |
| 9786 | 6491 |
| 128525 | 4431 |
| 8265 | 6288765 |
| 169 | 7 |
| 10002 | 10001 |
| 12951 | 39941 |
| 12349 | 12350 |
| 10067 | 222678 |
| 10548 | 999 |
| 128720 | 1029 |
| 129303 | 130000 |
| 127344 | 170 |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Numbers with Feeling™, Not Numbers with Feeling™
9786,6491
128525,4431
8265,6288795
169,7
10002,10001
12951,39941
12349,12350
10067,222678
10548,999
128720,1029
129303,130000
127344,170
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each number can be tested for whether it is a Number with Feeling™ without relying on the other numbers.
These are not the only examples of Numbers with Feeling™; many more exist.

What is the special rule these numbers conform to?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A number with feeling is a number that

> is an Emoji when converted to unicode (see the [full list of Emoji 5.0](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html) for reference)
> [image]